# Cycle through an array/range, with the values of another array/range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have an array....

```
 {eve, 20; adam, 60; helen, 80; paris, 5}
```

I would like to search the values of THAT array, with the values of THIS array....

```
 {eve; eve; helen; adam; helen}
```

to produce this...

```
 {20; 20; 80; 60; 80}
```

In sheets, the first array is in the range A1:B4, and the second is D1:D5

My initial attempt looked like this ....

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A4 = D1:D5, A1:B4, ""))
```

This obviously doesn't work, and I've been wracking my brains for the past 5 hours trying different tricks like placing $ signs in different range values, and things like...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A4 =indirect("D"&sequence(count(d1:d5))), A1:B4, ""))
```

I'm fairly new to this, so please for the love of all that is holy, release me from this living nightmare, and I will be forever grateful

Comment: I don't understand about your sources, array or cell range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for your array:

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP({"eve"; "eve"; "helen"; "adam"; "helen"},{"eve", 20; "adam", 60; "helen", 80; "paris", 5},2,false))
```

Formula for cell range:

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(D1:D5, A1:B4, 2, false))
```

Comment: Thank you didn't even think about trying vlookup!

Comment: Just one follow up question, would this still be possible if i wanted to pull names based on whether their attached number meets a condition? ie. =arrayformula(VLOOKUP({>20; <50; >8; =60; =5},{20, "eve"; 60, "adam"; 80, "helen"; 5, "paris"},2,false))

Comment: Change 2 with {1,2}